# GWT's http request builder returning empty response

Tags: java, gwt, httprequest, http-get

I have a GWT application with which I would like to get data from endomondo in JSON format and I can obtain it with following IRL :

```
http://api.mobile.endomondo.com/mobile/api/workout/list?authToken=XXXXXXXXXX
```

and I will get data like

```
{"data":[{"duration_sec":2710,"sport":0,"speed_kmh_avg":11.721935764889876,"device_workout_id":"6588152507813057122","feed_id":155634169,"sport2":0,"id":192960126,"altitude_m_max":227.3,"hydration":0.35771,"altitude_m_min":145.5,"has_playlist":false,"burgers_burned":1.075926,"start_time":"2013-05-21 18:57:04 UTC","calories":581,"speed_kmh_max":26.281,"distance_km":8.824012756347656,"has_points":true},]}
```

But somehow by calling this with GWT http request builder I cannot do it. What should I change in the code ?

```
String url = "http://api.mobile.endomondo.com/mobile/api/workout/list?authToken=XXXXXXXXXX";
RequestBuilder builder = new RequestBuilder(RequestBuilder.GET, url);


try {
      Request myrequest = builder.sendRequest(null, new RequestCallback() {

        public void onError(Request request, Throwable exception) {
           // Couldn't connect to server (could be timeout, SOP violation, etc.)

        }

        public void onResponseReceived(Request request, Response response) {
          if (200 == response.getStatusCode()) {
              trainingsJSON = JSONParser.parseStrict(response.getText());
              trainingsString = response.getText();
            Label l = new Label();
            l.setText("200 erros status code JSON DATA from endomondo " + response.getText()) ;

            RootPanel.get().add(l);
          } else {
            // Handle the error.  Can get the status text from response.getStatusText()
                Label l = new Label();
                l.setText("JSON DATA from endomondo 3rror part " + response.getText()) ;

                RootPanel.get().add(l);                   
          }
        }       
      });
    } catch (RequestException e) {
      // Couldn't connect to server        
    }
```

**EDIT**

I have tried adding

`builder.setHeader("Access-Control-Allow-Origin", "*");`

but with no luck.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you make CORS requests with GWT, you dont have to add any extra header to your request. What you must do, is check that the server is supporting CORS requests from your site.

If you are managing the site `http://api.mobile.endomondo.com`, you have to change the server code to return the appropriate CORS headers when the client sends an `OPTION` request.

In case of java server-side you have an example of how to handle CORS in this [page](https://code.google.com/p/gwtquery/wiki/Ajax#CORS_%28Cross_Origin_Resource_Sharing%29) using a `Filter`.

Note that CORS only works in modern browsers (EDITED: actually old version of certain browsers support it. See the list of browsers in @Thomas comments below).

Comment: Note: "modern browsers" meaning every one (Firefox, Chrome, Safari for years, Opera quite recently) but IE9- (IE10 is fine).

Comment: yep, IE9 is not in 'my' modern-browsers list. Thank Thomas

Comment: I also wanted to point out that "modern" here includes years-old browsers (Firefox 3.5, Safari 4.0, Chrome –all version? at least since 4.0–, Android 2.1) http://caniuse.com/cors